# c# console application run matlab function

Tags: c#, .net, matlab

I have some code written in Matlab however I wish to call this code from a C# console application.

I do not require any data to be returned from Matlab to my app (although if easy would be nice to see).

There appears to be a few options however not sure which is best. Speed is not important as this will be an automated task.

Comment: I've answered this solely because I've researched this recently and literally had the relevant webpage open. This information was not difficult to find or understand, and you must do better research before asking questions in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MATLAB has a .Net interface that's well-documented. What you need to do is covered in the [Call MATLAB Function from C# Client](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_external/call-matlab-function-from-c-client.html) article.

For a simple MATLAB function, say:

```
function [x,y] = myfunc(a,b,c) 
x = a + b; 
y = sprintf('Hello %s',c);
```

..it boils down to creating an `MLApp` and invoking the `Feval` method:

```
class Program 
{ 
    static void Main(string[] args) 
    { 
        // Create the MATLAB instance 
        MLApp.MLApp matlab = new MLApp.MLApp(); 

        // Change to the directory where the function is located 
        matlab.Execute(@"cd c:\temp\example"); 

        // Define the output 
        object result = null; 

        // Call the MATLAB function myfunc
        matlab.Feval("myfunc", 2, out result, 3.14, 42.0, "world"); 

        // Display result 
        object[] res = result as object[]; 

        Console.WriteLine(res[0]); 
        Console.WriteLine(res[1]); 
        Console.ReadLine(); 
    } 
}
```